# Simple flip with flash doesn't work

Tags: flash, animation, movieclip

I am trying to create a simple animation, juste a picture that need to move from left to write while rotating around the vertical axis.
I tried just to have the first position normal and the final position scaled at -100% in width but it also distort and move up and down.

I already did that in acstionscript but not just graphicaly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use more key frames in your tween. You should set more key frames than only the initial position and final position, so the flash player has a better idea as to how you had the animation in mind.

In your case: try setting the 0th position to 0% scaled, the 1/4th position to -25% scaled and so forth.

Comment: It seems that it is not possible to flip without skewing, then I find the only solution to scale the width -100% on first position -1% and a second one, 1% the fird to go to 100% at final position, but it's very hard, and really simpler in actionscript.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this Greg.

Use the actionscript 3 tween class.

convert the picture a movieclip say _movie1 and make sure the registration is

then
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

new Tween(movie1,"rotationY",None.easeIn,movie1.rotationY,movie1.rotationY+180,1,true);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

tweek the tween and ease to get more effects...

Answer (score 0):

I've just been struggling with this and it seems the only way to do it is to split the animation into two parts, with a blank keyframe in between. If you were, for example, flipping an object around a horizontal axis the first part would have the object going from full size to practically no height (say 1 pixel). In the second half, flip the object vertically when placing it on the stage and do a separate tween with if going from almost no height to full height. That transitions it without skewing.